# What are the cons and pros of docker use on windows virtual machines without cloud?

Tags: docker, windows-services, .net-core-3.0

I want to use docker to host .net core 3.0 worker services on windows based platform. We are using virtual machines not on cloud platform.

Do we really have to use docker on VMs or running service as windows service is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the use. What do you intend to run on the container/VM?

You can read more about it here:

[Deploy existing .NET apps as Windows containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modernize-with-azure-containers/modernize-existing-apps-to-cloud-optimized/deploy-existing-net-apps-as-windows-containers#what-are-containers-linux-or-windows)

[When to choose .NET Framework for Docker containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/net-core-net-framework-containers/net-framework-container-scenarios).